# Команда для добавления в автозагрузку в реестре

Tags: windows, bat, windows-7, реестр, автозагрузка

Нужна команда для батника, которая добавит определенный файл в реестр автозагрузки.

Раздел реестра:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ /t REG_SZ /v 0 /d "C:\killallhumans.exe" /f`